# window resizing is not working

Tags: css, html

in my screen  i have 3 main div ,when i resize the page the div content can not resize how can i solve this problem with out overflow property
the width of the content is now re sizable only the problem in height

```
height : calc (100%-(50px + 40px)
```

this is the style i give div for height

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: At least your code should be formatted as `height : calc(100% - (50px + 40px));`

Comment: Please share your code in fiddle or place below it..

Comment: `calc()` function accepts values with space separator, as @Rounin tells in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have understood your CSS declaration properly, but if I have, try rewriting it as:

```
div {
max-height: calc(100% - (50px + 40px));
}
```